# "query" property inadvertently added in Elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I recently updated an ElasticSearch server of ours from version 0.9 to 1.4, and when I imported a Mapping for the new ES, I saw this was added in the mapping:

```
"query": {
  "properties": {
    "match_all": {
      "type": "object"
     }
   }
 },
```

That snippet isn't in the mapping that I imported, but it always appears when I query `curl -X GET localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping?pretty`.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you accidentally created the index rather than querying it. IE, you posted to:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/myindex -d '"query": {
  "properties": {
    "match_all": {
      "type": "object"
     }
   }
 }'
```

which would create the index with that mapping, when you probably wanted:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search -d '"query": {
  "properties": {
    "match_all": {
      "type": "object"
     }
   }
 }'
```

which would just search.

Comment: I vaguely remember doing something like that actually. Do you know how I can reverse this so I keep the rest of the mapping, but I remove the "query" part?

Comment: You'll need to drop the index and recreate it with the desired mapping, unfortunately.